# Doing an MLT (More Like This) Query in Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using the recent Solr 4.2.1 solrj libraries.

I am trying to execute an MLT Query from a java program.  It works fine as long as I only provide small chunks in the stream.body, but that kind of defeats my purpose.

When I try to use the ContentStream I don't get a response back, when I do the solr.query, it makes another request.

It looks like the server is getting my solr.request() ok.  Appreciate any pointers.

Oh, and I am talking to a solr 3.6.1

Here is what I have so far:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStream;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStreamBase;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.*;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.ContentStreamUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils;

public class SolrJSearcher {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");


ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
String mltv[] = {"Big bunch of text for testing - redacted for brevity"};


String dvalues[] = {"mlt"};
String svalues[] = {"0"};


ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/mlt");
ContentStream cs = new ContentStreamBase.StringStream(mltv[0]);

up.addContentStream( cs);   


SolrQuery theQuery = new SolrQuery();;


theQuery.set("qt", dvalues);

up.setParam("start", "0");



try {
    solr.request(up);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

QueryResponse response = solr.query(theQuery);

SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
  System.out.println(results.get(i));
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, MoreLikeThis is meant to find documents similar to a document already in the index. If you're searching documents similar to an input string, then just insert a temporary item in your index before you do the query, and remove it afterwards.

I've been using the following successfully:

```
/*
 * Build up a MoreLikeThis query to retrieve documents 
 * similar to the one with id originalId
 */
private SolrQuery buildUpMoreLikeThisQuery(String field3, String originalId) {
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQueryType("/" + MoreLikeThisParams.MLT);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.MATCH_INCLUDE, true);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.MIN_DOC_FREQ, 1);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.MIN_TERM_FREQ, 1);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.MIN_WORD_LEN, 7);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.BOOST, false);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.MAX_QUERY_TERMS, 1000);
    query.set(MoreLikeThisParams.SIMILARITY_FIELDS,
            "field1,field2");
    query.setQuery("id:" + originalId);
    query.set("fl", "id,score");
    query.addFilterQuery("field3:" + field3);
    int maxResults = 20;
    query.setRows(maxResults);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks very much for spending some time on this. I'm not sure that this approach will work for what I need to do Here is the approach I am trying to take: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SolrJ-and-ContentStreams-td3256237.html  Re: SolrJ and ContentStreams

Comment: In the interest of good citizenship.  I think I have solved my own problem, and am posting the solution here.  Basically, I can do the query with a big chunk of data to MLT provided I change the method to POST e.g. QueryResponse response = solr.query(theQuery,METHOD.POST);  If I do that, I don't need to use the update handler at all.  Thanks to rcomblen, though for his help.

Comment: @nitramtheugly, please post this comment as an answer and accept it on your own behalf. IT will be more visible like this.